# Creating Buttons during runtime in Java

Tags: java, button, dynamic, runtime, creation

I want to add a number of Buttons to my Java application based on an array. Say if there are 10 objects in an array, I want to create 10 buttons. If I delete 2 objects in the array the buttons should also get deleted. I thought about 3 things to go on about this problem.

A for loop - but I think the buttons would just exist inside the loop and also I would not know how to name the buttons (the variable name not the label).
A Thread
A seperate class

I have no idea how I would do that though.

Can I actually name variables through loops?
Are any of my ideas practicable?

Comment: are u using java swing?

Comment: Yes, I am using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a button to a `JPanel` it will survive outside the for loop, so don't worry about it. Create a `JPanel` just for your buttons and keep track of those you add using an `ArrayList<JButton>`, so you'll be able to delete them as you need. To delete them from the  panel, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267593/6267019) answer. Remember to repaint (=refresh) the JPanel.

```
JButton button1 = ...;

// Add it to the JPanel
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635561/how-to-add-components-into-a-jpanel

ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
buttons.add(button1);

// Other stuff...

// It's time to get rid of the button
JButton theButtonIWantToRemove = buttons.get(0);
buttons.remove(0);

//Get the components in the panel
Component[] componentList = panel.getComponents();

//Loop through the components
for(Component c : componentList){
    //Find the components you want to remove
    if(c == theButtonIWantToRemove){
        //Remove it
        panel.remove(c);
    }
}

//IMPORTANT
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```